# How to parse multi-level XML file with python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, lxml

I have a multi-level XML file that needs to parse with python, I have xml or lxml. How do I parse? I could not find any useful solution.Please help me, thanks a lot! Ideally, I want to parse the XML file and convert to Python DataFrame.
This for loop does not work.

```
 for child in root:
     for element in child:
         for element in child:
             print(element.tag, element.attrib)
```

This is part of the result that I printed out with pretty print.

```
<Listings>
  <Listing>
    <Location>
      <City>Amagansett</City>
      <State>NY</State>
      <Zip>11930</Zip>
      <Latitude>4.12</Latitude>
      <Longitude>2.13</Longitude>
      <DisplayAddress>No</DisplayAddress>
    </Location>
    <ListingDetails>
      <Status>For Rent</Status>
      <Price>120000</Price>
      <ListingUrl>http://www.co.com/listing.aspx?   Region=LI3&amp;ListingID=122</ListingUrl>
      <MlsId>122</MlsId>
      <DateListed>2011-06-10</DateListed>
      <NewDevelopment>N</NewDevelopment>
    </ListingDetails>
    <BasicDetails>
      <PropertyType>Other</PropertyType>
      <Description>Rental Registration #: the master suite has a lavish bath and its own terrace with small ocean views..</Description>
      <Bedrooms>5</Bedrooms>
      <Bathrooms>4</Bathrooms>
      <FullBathrooms>4</FullBathrooms>
      <HalfBathrooms>0</HalfBathrooms>
      <LivingArea>5775</LivingArea>
      <LotSize>0.8</LotSize>
    </BasicDetails>

  </Listing>
</Listings>
```

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: I believe you want `elem.tag` and `elem.text`

Comment: Sure, hold on. thank you.

Comment: I removed the pic. The pic is not the code, it is just a screenshot of the xml file that I needed to parse.

Answer (score 2):

I think I got it!
this is what I used.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree       
res=[]
for child in root:
    r=[]
    for element in child:
        for element in element:
            new=element.text
            r.append(new)

    res.append(r) 
print (res)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use xmltodict - as it is easier in my opinion.

```
 import xmltodict


 with open('file.xml',encoding="utf8") as datafile:

   doc = xmltodict.parse(datafile.read())

for row in doc['Listings']['Listing']['Location']:
 try:

        #City
       print(row['City'],'City')

    except Exception:
                   pass
```

I have used Try and expect exception - as the XML files usually have different structure so you might get an error trying to get something that does not exist.